# Support Arabic language in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, internationalization, translation, arabic, database

I want to build my MEAN application with an Arabic frontend.

I was searching the web for a solution to make mongodb support Arabic, but thusfar I've had no luck.

Is it possible to support Arabic for my current mongodb (which I download from mongodb.org)? Thank you in advance!

Comment: in version 3.2: MongoDB Enterprise includes support for [Arabic](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/)

Comment: Yes I saw that, but what is the difference between enterprise edition and the normal one which I download from mongodb.org

Comment: Currently facing the same question, has anyone established if MongoDB community supports Arabic?

Comment: After calling mongodb customer service, they confirmed that the community version doesn't support Arabic, so I changed the entire DB and switched back to MySQL.  You need to get enterprise edition to support Arabic

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB Community** doesn't support Arabic. **MongoDB Enterprise** has support for Arabic.